# Using prune and -out with find command could not exclude directory

Tags: bash, shell

I have `level1//a/0.jpg , level1//b/0.jpg`

I want to exclude 0.jpg in b directory and do some sed....
but having this it doesn't work

```
find level1/ -name 0.jpg -prune level1/b -exec sed ....
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood what `-prune` does. It sound like you actually want `-not -path` like so:

```
find level1 -name 0.jpg -not -path 'level1/b/*'
```

Comment: @ArthurAlexsanyan Worked for me. Did you make sure to remove the slash after `level1`?

Comment: Thanks it works 
but what if I move 0.png from b directory deeper like level1/test/b
in this case I get .so how can I ignore in all subdirectories

Comment: @ArthurAlexsanyan `level1/test/b` is a different tree then `level1/b`, you would have to list it too  `-not -path 'level1/test/*'`

Comment: It was a mistake I mean if I do like this level1/b/test/0.jpg in that case it still brings

Comment: I want to exclude other directories whatever they include

Comment: @ArthurAlexsanyan That's strange. I can't reproduce that on macOS or Linux.

Comment: @ArthurAlexsanyan The `level1/b/*` needs to be in quotes, otherwise the wildcard is expended by the shell.